# Ruby on rails link_to global class?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to add class by default in a link_to helper?
This global setting should prevent me manually adding the :class option
everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

application_helper.rb

```
def nav_link(text, controller, action="index", class)
    link_to_unless_current text, :id => nil,
                                 :action => action,
                             :controller => controller,
                                     :class => class
end
```

Views.html.erb

```
<%= nav_link "text", "controller", "action", "MYCLASS" %>
```

Comment: No exactly the thing I was looking for, but you pointed me in the right direction.